# Display different colors and message when button is clicked/hovered on

Tags: javascript, html, css

I require help in making this code work so as to show different colors and message when the required button is clicked/ hovered on

I would like to:

1. Change the background of the page when the button `'colours'` is hovered upon
2. Show a message when button `'msg'` is clicked upon

As I am a beginner I don't know what actually wrong with the code but the function doesn't initiate by itself is all I know

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<script language="javascript">
  function f1() {
    document.bgcolor = "blue";
    window.setTimeout("f2", 1200);
  }

  function f2() {
    document.bgcolor = "indigo";
    window.setTimeout("f3", 1200);
  }

  function f3() {
    document.bgcolor = "voilet";
    window.setTimeout("f4", 1200);
  }

  function f4() {
    document.bgcolor = "green";
    window.setTimeout("f5", 1200);
  }

  function f5() {
    document.bgcolor = "purple";
    window.setTimeout("f6", 1200);
  }

  function f6() {
    document.bgcolor = "yellow";
    window.setTimeout("f7", 1200);
  }

  function f7() {
    document.bgcolor = "orange";
    window.setTimeout("f8", 1200);
  }

  function f8() {
    document.bgcolor = "red";
    window.setTimeout("f1", 1200);
    f1();
  }

  function msg() {
    window.status = "display 7 distinct colours"
  }
</script>

<body>
  <center>
    <input type="button" name="b1" value="colors" onMouseOver="f1()">
    <input type="button" name="b2" value="msg" onClick="msg()">
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not the problem, but instead of `window.setTimeout("functionName", 1200);`, just use `setTimeout(functionName, 1200);`. don't pass in strings, and you don't need the `window` prefix.

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks will try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. It's a bit different, but using JS will report a "Maximum Call Stack Trace Exceeded" error which can not be bypassed in any way from what I've seen. As a workaround, I created an inline CSS stylesheet using CSS animations that do the same colour changing, every 1200ms, but the button will enable the stylesheet instead of setting the colour. The stylesheet is disabled by default.

Also, due to all browsers not supporting window.status, I changed that to window.alert, which is supported.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Colors</title>
  </head>
  <script language="javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("style").disabled=true;
  }
  function colors()
  {
      document.getElementById("style").disabled=false;
  }
  function msg()
  {
      window.alert("display 7 distinct colours");
  }
  </script>
  <body>
  <style id="style">
      body {
          animation-duration: 8400ms;
          animation-name: bgcolorchange;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-timing-function:steps(1, end);
      }
      @keyframes bgcolorchange {
          0% {
              background-color: blue;
          }
          12.5% {
              background-color: indigo;
          }
          25% {
              background-color: violet;
          }
          37.5% {
              background-color: green;
          }
          50% {
              background-color: purple;
          }
          62.5% {
              background-color: yellow;
          }
          75% {
              background-color: orange;
          }
          87.5% {
              background-color: red;
          }
          100% {
              background-color: blue;
          }
    }
    </style>
    <center>
        <input type="button" name="b1" value="colors" onMouseOver="colors()">
        <input type="button" name="b2" value="msg" onClick="msg()">
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wait what, you can disable style elements like that?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes my friend CSS supports transitions and animations on a basic level which we can use to do the job

Comment: @samyo: No, I'm talking about the `.disabled` attribute you're setting on the stylesheet. I've never seen that before. I've got plenty of experience with css animations...

Comment: @Cerbrus yes we can do it, although we don't generally use it but we can do it nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking for

Pure simple Javascript below -

```js
  var bx = document.body;
  var colorArr = ["blue", "indigo", "voilet", "green", "purple", "yellow", "orange", "red"];
  var counter = 0;
  var ifHover = false;
  var interval;

function changeClr() {
  if(ifHover != true) return;
  bx.style.background = colorArr[counter];
  counter++;
  if(counter==colorArr.length) counter=0;
  interval = setTimeout(changeClr, 1200);
}

function startClr(){ ifHover = true; clearInterval(interval); changeClr(); }

function stopClr(){ ifHover = false; }

function msg() {
  alert("display 7 distinct colours");
}
```

```html
<center>
  <input type="button" onmouseover="startClr()" onmouseout="stopClr()" value="color">
  <input type="button" onclick="msg()" value="msg">
</center>
```